# Wordpress Permalink Issue with index.php

Tags: php, wordpress

Why is this sample domain www.example.com/about-us is not working even though I activate the .htaccess

```
AddHandler php-stable .php
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

also when you navigate also this link www.example.com/index.php/about-us it will redirect you to this www.example.com/about-us which is not working but when you navigate this www.example.com/Index.php/about-us that's the time the url is working. Please help. It host on godaddy

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are having a `mod_rewrite` issue with your hosting. You can create a .php page on your server lets call it `phpinfo.php` and write the following code in it

```
<?php
   phpinfo();
?>
```

Open this page in browser and look for `mod_rewrite` setting. It needs to be on for permalink to work.

Now, go to your `WP Admin Panel -> Settings -> Permalink` and choose `/post_name/` Wordpress will automatically write in .htaccess file (provided it can access it).

If mod_rewrite is not enabled on your server, there is no way other than contacting your hosting provider to enable it. It is enabled by all hosting providers still you have to cross check using phpinfo.

Following is a perfectly valid .htaccess file for WordPress

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Also ensure that `apache.conf` is configured to be overridden by .htaccess file. Apache settings like `AllowOverride none;` ensure `.htaccess` is not honored.

Answer (score 0):

As per the query you explained, I would like to suggest that you

go to `WP Admin Panel -> Settings -> Permalink`

Then select the radio button in front of `/post_name/`

Then go to `WP Admin Panel -> Appearance -> Menus`

Now check that you have all pages used in Menus, or is there any custom link you have used?

Also check your `.htaccess`

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```